# Android sensor TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR gives very delayed results

Tags: android, rotation, sensors

I'm implementing a sensor listener using Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR, calculating yaw,pitch and roll using the following code:

```
    // Convert the rotation-vector to a 4x4 matrix.
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrixFromVector, event.values);
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrixFromVector,
            SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
            mRotationMatrix);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientationVals);

    // Optionally convert the result from radians to degrees
    orientationVals[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[0]);
    orientationVals[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[1]);
    orientationVals[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[2]);

    tv1.setText("Yaw:" + orientationVals[0]);
    tv2.setText("Pitch:" + orientationVals[1]);
    tv3.setText("Roll:" + orientationVals[2]);


}
```

However, on our test device (a Galaxy S3 Mini), the values returned from the sensor each update lag far behind the actual device orientation. Pitch is particularly bad, taking a full 5-6 seconds to catch up to the actual device.

Testing on a Note 3 also has some lag, but nowhere near as bad, so my question is, is the TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR results I'm getting on the S3 mini a result of hardware limitations? I've seen lots of examples on StackOverflow of people implementing their own orientation values by compositing other sensors, mainly accelerometer, magnetometer and gyroscope rather than rely on this sensor so I'm wondering if I'm doing it wrong.